# Problem using pgr_createTopology

Tags: pgrouting

When I run `select pgr_createTopology('public.roads', 0.0001, 'geom', 'id');`,
all I get is "FAIL". The roads table has these fields:

id (integer)
source (integer)
target (integer)
geom (geometry LineStringM,3006)

What am I missing? I have been unable to find a list of requirements for the network table, which I create using FME. I use pgRouting 2.2.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The geometrytype should be LineString, not LineStringM.

Try changing your geom column to LineString with this:

```
ALTER TABLE public.roads 
  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(LineString,3006)
  USING ST_Force2D(geom);
```

Comment: Ah, yes, that helped. The query now works. Thank you.

Comment: should check as accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Debes tener errores topológicos, verifica que no tengas líneas duplicadas, arcos, etc.. debes tener una capa super limpia topológicamente hablando.

---

English translation:

You must have topological errors, verify that you do not have duplicate lines, arcs, etc. You must have a super clean layer topologically speaking.

Comment: GIS SE is an English-language forum. Please translate non-English text in answers, much as I have done with Google Translate above.